# Limit file types dragged into web browser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have a web browser I'm using in my VB.net form to which I drag *.CTB files. At present I can drag any file type into the browser can I limit this to CTB file extensions only and if the user ties to drag in any other extension that a message box appears quoting that the file must be ctb extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is handling the drag/drop functionality so you might not be able to (easily) intercept that. Instead, you could handle the `Navigating` method and cancel the navigation if the file type is incorrect. (You might want to do a more robust check for the extension).

```
Private Sub WebBrowser_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs)
    'get file extension
    Dim ext As String = e.Url.ToString.Substring(e.Url.ToString.Length - 3)
    If ext <> "CTB" Then
        e.Cancel = True
        MessageBox.Show("Only CTB files are allowed")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the following two errors the first says substring' is nota member of system.uri (change the uri to url still no difrence and name s is not declared?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a VB.NET developer, but you need to convert the url to a string first. I think that's how you do it (updated my answer).

Comment: The code to check the extension would be better as something like: `If Path.GetExtension(e.Url.AbsolutePath).Equals(".ctb", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then`